# Cascade deletion of products and deletion in all tables by id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a product table. I do the removal of products and I also want to remove this product from the float, remove the likes from the table, and from the comments table.

```
DELETE FROM COMMENTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
DELETE FROM LIKES_PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
DELETE FROM BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
```

The fact is that the product table is associated with the primary key with the table. How to integrate these queries and execute cascade delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add cascading deletion constraints to the other tables.  For example, try the following on the `COMMENTS` table:

```
ALTER TABLE COMMENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_fk) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (PRODUCT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It is important that you add this constraint *before* you try doing:

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
```

The reason for this is that if you remove parent records in the `PRODUCTS` table, and then try to add the constraint to the child table, you will get an error.  The reason for this error is that now there are child records which point to parent records no longer existing.  If that did happen to you, you could fix it by manually deleting the child records from the other tables.

With this constraint in place, deleting `PRODUCT_ID = 1` in the `PRODUCTS` table will also cause all matching records in the `COMMENTS` table to also be deleted.

It is also possible to define your tables using a `CREATE TABLE` statement which has foreign constraints.  But, since your tables already exist, the `ALTER TABLE` option I gave above would probably be more useful to you.

Comment: That is, when I delete a product, do I have to fulfill four such requests?

Comment: No, if you have foreign keys with cascading delete n place on all tables, then deleting a product will automatically delete all dependent rows in all other tables.

Comment: I delete the product `delete from PRODUCTS where PRODUCT_ID = 39;
ALTER TABLE COMMENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_fk) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (PRODUCT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;` and get an error `ERROR:  update or delete on table "products" violates foreign key constraint "bookmarks_products_product_id_fkey" on table "bookmarks_products"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(39) is still referenced from table "bookmarks_products".`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MegaRoks See my updated answer.  You should add the constraints _first_.  To fix your current situation, run `DELETE FROM COMMENTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 39`.  Then, add the constraint again, and it should work.